# Let $k$ be a positive integer. Find the largest power of 3 which divides $10^k - 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Find the largest power of 3 which divides $10^k - 1$.

It is obvious that 9 always divides the number and 27 and 81 divide the number if k is multiple of 3 and 9 respectively. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: This is an application of the so called [Lifting the exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma). Use that as a buzzword to find several examples of its use on our site.

Comment: [The search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22lifting+the+exponent%22).

Comment: [An example on divisibility by powers of three](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348590/11619)